# Scala generics in an abstract function

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance

There is an abstract class `Animal`.
`Animal` is extended by `Dog` and `Cow`.
`Animal` has an abstract function `copy`. When called on `Dog` is should return `Dog` and when called on `Cow` - `Cow`.

```
abstract class Animal[T] {
  def copy[CT <: Animal[T]] (): CT
}

class Dog[T] extends Animal[T] {
  def copy = new Dog[T]()
}
```

This gives an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "This gives an error.". Don't make us guess. Give the error. And the error in this case should give you a clue (since it says the copy from Animal is not implemented by Dog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially `CT` must be invariant for your approach to work.  Your concrete implementation of Dog has no control over the type of `CT`, for example it's impossible to account for this with your approach (hence the compiler error):

```
new Dog[Int]().copy[Cow[Int]]()
```

Your concrete implementation gives me a `Dog` but I wanted a `Cow`.  This is because your `copy` method cannot possibly satisfy the return type parameter variance.  If all you need is one return type for the `copy` method you could employ this alternative (inspired by the same problem as it occurs in C++):

```
abstract class Animal[T, SubType <: Animal[T, _]] {
  def copy (): SubType
}

class Dog[T] extends Animal[T, Dog[T]] {
  override def copy() = new Dog[T]
}

val animal: Animal[Int, Dog[Int]] = new Dog()
val dogCopy: Dog[Int] = animal.copy()
```

Here's another simpler (not as obvious) approach.  Scala permits you to override not just the implementation of a method, but also the return type to some degree:

```
abstract class Animal[T] {
  def copy (): Animal[T]
}

class Dog[T] extends Animal[T] {
  override def copy() = new Dog[T]
}

val dog = new Dog[Int]()
val dogCopy: Dog[Int] = dog.copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `copy` method in `Dog` does not have the same signature as the `copy` method in `Animal` (`Animal` has a type parameter and `Dog` does not), so the Scala compiler thinks you haven't implemented it for `Dog`. It looks like you're trying to work around the fact that `copy` should return the sub-type. You can use a self-type for this:

```
abstract class Animal[T] { self: T =>
  def copy: T = this
}

class Dog extends Animal[Dog]
```

Unless you had something else in mind for the type parameter?

It might also be more prudent to use F-bounded polymorphism in this case, to verify that `T` is a sub-type of `Animal`.

```
abstract class Animal[T <: Animal[T]]
```